# Scrape specific text within html tags that occur after (outside) of other tags

Tags: python, select, xhtml, scrapy

I am currently using [*scrapy*](http://scrapy.org/) for python and trying to retrieve information from a website with a source code similar to this:

```
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Date</th>
    <td>10/17/2001</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Title</th>
    <td>Harry Potter</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Author</th>
    <td>J.K. Rowling</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
```

*Harry Potter* is the text string I wish to retrieve. However, I cannot use the traditional Xpath delimiters since there are multiple instances of this code snippet throughout the page (only with different text between the th/td tags--as seen in the code above). All of the th tags are prefaced with a scope="row" attribute.

Additionally, I cannot scrape just the x-th instance of the tag because each webpage I am scraping has a variable number of instances.

Is there a way to obtain text (such as *Harry Potter*) that follows a particular string of text (such as title) in *scrapy*?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I assume that you're using scrapy (in python), but what *in particular* have you tried, and what's failing?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the text content of the `td` element following the `th` element with `scope="row"` and containing "Title"?

Comment: I wish to retrieve specifically the "Harry Potter" text which occurs only after the "Title" text. There are, however, multiple instances of that code throughout the page (only with different text between th and td tags). Hence I must point the xpath towards the actual text in addition to the usual tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
//tr/th[@scope="row"][.="Title"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try. In General, learn to be XPath.

```
/tr/td/text()
```

Comment: I may have been unclear, but there are multiple cases of tr/td/text() throughout the page. This would yield every single instance instead of the one I wanted. (The one I want occurs after a specific "Title" as in the code above.

Comment: I said - teach XPath. /tr/td[n]/text() where n is the ordinal number of this design of such.